# How do I set my custom IdGenerator for OpenTelemetry extension in Quarkus?

Tags: java, quarkus

I followed documentation https://quarkus.io/guides/opentelemetry#id-generator, but this way is either incomplete or just does not work. According to the doc that is suppose to work somehow auto-magically, but application continue to use default random generator instead of using AwsXrayIdGenerator that I'm trying to provide.
So, should I register this class in parameters? What am I supposed to do if I'm not getting the expected result?

Comment: You shouldn't post the answer in the question, better post it as separate answer and approve so others can find it

Answer (score 0):

Moved my answer from question by @siggemannen suggestion

After hours of searching and debugging I finally figured out that I had to formally inject IdGenerator class somewhere, that will kick in corresponding logic in Instances.resolveBeans() and get the instance of IdGenerator from the CustomConfig.idGenerator() method (or any other method annotated as @Produces). It was interesting, but not so pleasant learning. A little bit more help from the doc would be nice.